# missing minGW files

Tags: c++, mingw

I am trying to run a test for my class, but my build.bat did not build correctly.
It says ld.exe is missing in minGW folders.
I already tried to reinstall minGW.

C:\Users\HHT\lab_00\build>g++ -std=gnu++11 -o testB ../_tests/_test_files/testB.cpp ../includes/stub/stub.cpp ../includes/array_functions/array_functions.cpp -Igoogletest/googletest/include
-pthread -Lgoogletest/build/lib -lgtest
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread

Answer (score 0):

No, it says the library pthread cannot be located.
ld(.exe) is the linker complaining it cannot find it.
Provide proper path to library with -Lmysuper/secret/path/to/location or have the location in PATH in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I missed one of the installations in minGW.
It all good now.